# Make ios app "invisible" on app store

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I want to remove my "ready for sale" ios app from all markets so it´s no longer available for purchase, but still be able to provide updates for existing users. Is this possible?

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you must have it available for anyone to download/purchase if you're going to provide updates to it.

Standard Apple procedure, I'm afraid. Apple has to review everything to avoid sneaky app updates getting in the App Store.

You could just provide one last update and then remove it, if you're going to remove it from the store.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. Removing it from App Store removes it completely, meaning that you will no longer be able to provide updates.

What you could do is buy an enterprise account, which I believe will give you the opportunity to distribute applications without it being on the App Store. More information on that can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Ok, thank you. We have 1000+ users now so I guess the the enterprise solution is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to decrease the likelyhood of new customers, you could raise the price really high and put "do not buy" in the app's description.

Answer (score 1):

Check Availability date in Rights & Pricing section in your Application whether it is prior to current date or not.

Another reason is if your Application is Paid then you have to check whether Paid Application contract is pending or What ? If it is so you have to fill All the details related to IOS Paid Application contract first.

Hope this helps to everybody.